# How to index your Silverlight application in search engine?

Tags: .net, silverlight, seo, search-engine

Well, I have a Silverlight application with many internal pages, and I want search engine to index my Silverlight content. 
Besides I want to manage my Silverlight content for search engine and reader effectively.

How can I do Search Engine Optimization “SEO” for Silverlight?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has totally been thought about. ;) Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/03/25/silverlight-3-and-seo.aspx

Notice if you Google for "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=+Silverlight+Store+Wireless+Keyboard+7000" that you'll get a nice text representation. The app gave that text to the robot (since Google's robots don't have Silverlight installed! ;) ) but the user gets a great experience.

Comment: @Scott Hanselman: YES, the result is great for both Bing and Google...No worry about SEO for Silverlight app ;)

http://www.bing.com/search?hl=en&q=+Silverlight+Store+Wireless+Keyboard+7000
OR
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=+Silverlight+Store+Wireless+Keyboard+7000

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question.  From a conceptual point of view, I don't think Silverlight applications are intended to be indexed. Silverlight apps are interactive stateful applications, not stateless web pages containing information and page requests.

Web pages can also act as applications (through AJAX and the like) but still are stateless pages.

Silverlight would fit in with flash pages and java applets when considering search engine optimisation.

Comment: After a bit of a deeper look, Microsoft has thought about this topic. Check out this whitepaper about it: 
http://silverlight.net/learn/whitepapers/seo.aspx

Comment: Yep done :) I wonder how application security models in the future will handle search engine caching if more and more apps become browser based...